# Is there a way to generate a UUID where the first few bytes are fixed depending on inputs?

Tags: java, uuid, uniqueidentifier

Is there a way to generate UUID where we can control the first few bytes of a UUID, based on inputs?

For example, I would like a function like:

```
string generateUUID(string input);
```

where if I called it like the following:

```
generateUUID('a') = 00000001-6f42-4d44-acc4-fda717886945
generateUUID('a') = 00000001-9279-48c1-8695-ff088504b800
generateUUID('a') = 00000001-2a6d-4cba-85d5-aabe94bdb5bd

generateUUID('b') = 00000002-2a6d-4cba-85d5-aabe94bdb5bd
generateUUID('b') = 00000002-b46f-4427-83d5-f1244a9f1102
generateUUID('b') = 00000002-5de1-4b7c-94be-5bf07a749e82
```

etc.

Therefore, if the first 8 characters of the uuid is 00000001, then I know 'a' was the input, etc.

Is something like this available?

Comment: Why do you need to change 8 bytes based on the value of 8 bits? This is seriously wasteful, and reduces the space of distinct UUIDs considerably. Why you you think you need to do this at all?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I need to identify the originator of a uuid without any other information, and I'm trying to figure out if something like this is doable without affecting the quality of the uuid.

Answer (score 2):

Just generate a UUID normally, such as with [`UUID.randomUUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()), then convert it to a string with [`UUID.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString()), and then finally replace the first 8 characters as desired.

Comment: Good.  Simple.  However, it is worth noting that by doing this you are increasing the risk of UUID collisions by 2^N where N is the number of bits that you are stealing.  In this case N is 24.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  At what point does N become significant?  For example, if I only use the first 2 or 3 character, does the probability of collision decrease to insignificant?

Answer (score 0):

UUID have a method: public static UUID fromString(String name). It's what you need

Comment: But how do you generate the name with the appropriate properties?

Comment: This method is deterministic. I think OP still wants randomness.